# FLIXEL: hexagonal tiles not seamlessly tiling with each other

Tags: flixel

I'm making a hex grid for our project using as3. I wonder why my hex grid isn't tiling properly.

Running my code within Flash CS6 produces seamless tiling

[image]

but on FlashDevelop it looks like this

[image]

Here is my code (in FlashDevelop):

```
    public class PlayState extends FlxState {
    private var player:PlayerSprite;
    private var hexMap:GenerateGrid;

    protected var hexagonWidth:int = 128;
    protected var hexagonHeight:int = 132;
    protected var hexagonNumber:Number = 0;
    protected var gridX_Size:int = 7;
    protected var gridY_Size:int = 10;

    public function PlayState() {

    }

    override public function create():void {
        FlxG.mouse.show();

        for (var yPos:int = 0; yPos < gridY_Size; yPos++) {
            for (var xPos:int = 0; xPos < gridX_Size; xPos++) {
                var hexagonX_Pos:Number = hexagonHeight * xPos + (yPos % 2) * hexagonWidth / 2;
                var hexagonY_Pos:Number = hexagonHeight * yPos / 4 * 3;
                hexagonNumber = xPos + yPos * gridX_Size;
                hexMap = new GenerateGrid(hexagonX_Pos - hexagonWidth, hexagonY_Pos - hexagonHeight);
                this.add(hexMap);
            }
        }
```

And for the class where the hex tiles are drawn

```
    public class GenerateGrid extends FlxSprite {
    [Embed(source = "../res/hextile_grass.png")] private var HexGrassPng:Class;

    public function GenerateGrid(X:Number = 0, Y:Number = 0):void {
        super(X, Y);

        var hex:FlxSprite = new FlxSprite();
        hex = loadGraphic(HexGrassPng, false, false);
        hex.x = X;
        hex.y = Y;
    }

    override public function update():void {
        //super.update();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** : 
EDIT: I have noticed my mistake a while ago. Code should be `var hexagonX_Pos:Number = hexagonWidth * xPos + (yPos % 2) * hexagonWidth / 2;`

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be it's a floating point precision difference (do the two environments use different runtimes/sandboxes? I'm not very familiar with flash).

It looks like yPos is always turning out fine. My suspicion is that it has something to do with "(yPos % 2)", try yPos as a float instead of an int. A little hack that could fix it if that doesn't work is to negate a small constant off of your resultant xPos, tweak it untill it looks just right. Something like:

```
var hexagonX_Pos:Number = hexagonHeight * xPos + (yPos % 2) * hexagonWidth / 2 - 0.4;
```

This isn't very flexible if hexagonHeight/hexagonHeight can change though. You would have to derrive the value to negate based on hexagonHeight, that's if my fix even helps :)

Comment: My bad. I've only noticed until now that instead of using `hexagonWidth` to calculate for the horizontal spacing I've used `hexagonHeight`. Guess I need some sleep. Thanks though! :)

Comment: @fierron please click the checkmark next to this answer if it solved your problem